# Is it possible to make a push notification that doesn't open the app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want a push notification where you could tap yes or no.If yes is tapped it would NOT open the app.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not possible on iOS 6 unless you have a "Newsstand" app.

I've heard many of the newsstand-only features will be available to all apps in iOS 7 but I haven't had time to look into it yet. Maybe someone who knows more will answer.

Comment: Ok, I do have Xcode 5 and ios 7 so if anyone does know that would be great if they could post

Comment: Since the iOS dev centre is offline I can't look it up, but I expect what you're trying to do is possible on iOS 7. It is definitely not possible on iOS 6.

Comment: OK @matt and abhi, but if i cant do this could i make it with two buttons that both open the app?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 6 can't do this - all Push notifications need to be treated as if they'll display to the user, and if they get a push when the app isn't open, it will take them to the app if they tap "Yes".

As @eran pointed out, you could modify the push notification bundle to make it only display 1 button.

iOS 7 is currently NDA so can't be discussed here. That said, if you have Xcode 5, you should have the developer doc site basically downloaded. Look at the Multitasking Guide and the Release notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two buttons and none of them opens the app, why do you need two buttons?

If you pass null to the action-loc-key parameter, you'll get a single button that dismisses the alert without opening the app.

Comment: Becasue the button will answer a question and depending on the response it will trigger an action. Is it possible to make it so both yes and no buttons open the app.

Comment: @jonathan One button should be "answer the question" and the other button should be "i don't want to answer the question".

Comment: @jonathan It's not possible. Only one of the buttons can open the app.